# C# - Generic interface that extends generic parameter

Tags: c#

Is it possible to define a generic interface that extends the interface's generic parameter?

E.g. (this doesn't compile since inheriting `T` is not possible)

```
public interface IInsecurableService<T>: T { }
```

This way I'd like to add services to a DI container that are capable of some functions, while the same service without the extensions does still exists / can still be registered.

Comment: You cannot inherit a type at runtime(well, maybe with reflection)

Comment: Can you please add example of desired usage? Maybe you are looking for something like  `interface IInsecurableService<T> where T : IInsecurableService<T>`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Given generics are used at compile time, you are not necessarily inheriting at runtime. But because of the complications it causes with overrides, it's specifically disallowed, see answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[ECMA-335](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-335_5th_edition_december_2010.pdf), which defines the CLR, explicitly excludes this scenario**, and gives a rationale (section §9.1, my bold):

> A generic parameter, on its own, **cannot be used to specify the base class, or any implemented interfaces.** So, for example, ``` .class ... G``1<T> extends !0 ``` is invalid. However, it is valid for the base class, or interfaces, to  use that generic parameter when nested within another generic type. For example, ``` .class ... G``1<T> extends class H``1<!0> ``` and ``` .class ... G``1<T> extends class B``2<!0,int32> ``` are valid.
>
> [*Rationale:* This permits checking that generic types are valid at definition time rather than at instantiation time. e.g., in ``` .class ... G``1<T> extends !0 ```, we do not know what methods would override what others because no information is available about the base class; indeed, we do not even know
> whether `T` is a class: it might be an array or an interface.  Similarly, for ``` .class ... C``2<(!1)T,U> ``` where we are in the same situation of knowing nothing about the base class/interface definition. *end rationale*]

---

**[ECMA-334](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-334_5th_edition_december_2017.pdf), which defines the C# language spec, also excludes it** (section §18.2.4):

> The explicit base interfaces can be constructed interface types (§9.4, §18.2). A base interface cannot be a type parameter on its own, though it can involve the type parameters that are in scope.

Also section §15.2.4.2

> The base class specified in a class declaration can be a constructed class type (§9.4). A base class cannot be a type parameter on its own (§9.5), though it can involve the type parameters that are in scope.